# I have to search for a file with extension .txt, but the path is changing every day

Tags: python

I have a problem with file management.
I have to search for a file with extension .txt, but the path is changing every day.

I have an another file which contain the actual path, I can store it in a string, but when I
give the searching algorithm the windows drop an error message.

Here my script:

```
path= 'c:\..... this is the path what I get back from an another script'

os.chdir(path)
for files in os.listdir("."):``
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        print files
```

Error message: WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:....'

Comment: Try making `path` a raw string: `path = r'C:\foo\...`.

Comment: Is the path that you get from another script the path to a *directory*, or the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
path= 'c:/..... this is the path what I get back from an another script'

os.chdir(path)
for files in os.listdir("."):``
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        print files
```

`/` instead of `\`

Answer (score 0):

this out to do the trick.

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join

path = 'c:\\test'
print glob(join(path, '*.txt'))
```